# ASP .NET, update page when executing a task

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to update a label text to show the current state of a task that starts when clicking on a button.
So when the task starts the label shows "Generating" and when it ends the label shows "Generated". It seemed simple....

Here goes a very simplified code to show what i've been trying:

First, i've tried a BackgroundWorker

Default.aspx:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
  <ContentTemplate>
   <asp:Button Id="btn1" runat="server" Text="Run"
                             OnClick="btn1_Click"/>
   <asp:Label ID="lbl1" runat="server" Text="Not Generated"/>
  </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Default.aspx.cs:

```
protected void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lbl1.Text = "Generating";

    var bgw = new BackgroundWorker();

    bgw.DoWork += (_, __) =>
    {
        // This Sleep represents time used for an imaginary task :)
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
    };
    bgw.RunWorkerCompleted += (_, __) =>
    {
        lbl1.Text = "Generated";
    };
    bgw.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

Only appears "Generated" when the task ends, but no "Generating" when the task starts.

Then i tried using a task instead:

```
protected void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lbl1.Text = "Generating";
    this.MyTaskEvent += _Default_MyTaskEvent;
    Task task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(new Action(DoWork));
}

private void DoWork()
{
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
    MyTaskEvent?.Invoke();
}

private void _Default_MyTaskEvent()
{
    lbl1.Text = "Generated";
    // Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
}
```

But in this case only the "Generating" text appears but it does not change to "Generated" when the task has ended.
Also, i tried putting Response.Redirect("Default.aspx"); at the end of _Default_MyTaskEvent() but i got an exception saying something like "Response not available in this context".

I'm beginning to think that this is not as easy as i was thinking.
Am i forgetting something, doing someting wrong or this is not the approach i should take?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the UpdateProgress control. Or use javascript (update panels use js) to change the UI.

Answer (score 0):

since you are using updatepanel, use UpdateProgress control as recommended by @wazz as below:

```
    <asp:UpdateProgress ID="updProgress"
    AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel1"
    runat="server">
        <ProgressTemplate>           
        <img alt="progress" src="images/progress.gif"/>
           Processing...           
        </ProgressTemplate>
    </asp:UpdateProgress>
```

Then in your button click event, you need to await the call and make method async else asp.net will not know when method is completed.

```
protected async void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Task task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(new Action(DoWork));
    // do other stuff
    await task1;
}
```